# Finding guards for your gutters when you don't know the make or model

Tags: roof, drainage, gutters

Several years ago I let the guy who pressure washed our house convince me to take out the gutter guards. I have come to deeply regret this decision. My gutters are constantly clogging, and I'm terrified of heights, so now every 4 - 5 months I have to muster the courage to get up on an extension ladder and de-clog our gutters.

I want to replace the guards but we threw them away back when he took them off. There is no brand or name of any kind anywhere on my gutter system, at least that I can find. They are tin/metal white gutters approximatey 4.5 inches wide (measured from the two points below):

[image]

Is there a way to tell what the make/model of my gutter system is, so that I can buy the right guards for it? If not, do they make "universal" 4.5" gutter guards that should somehow snap into my system? If not, is there any generic/universal solution here that would result with my gutters being guarded against leaves and sticks?

Comment: Most guards are generic, so usually just need to know the width.  Most metal gutters are made on site by one of the local gutter guys/girls.

Comment: Only "seamless" gutter is made onsite. Most, like this, comes in 16' lengths.

Comment: @isherwood In my area (Maryland) most are made onsite. Funny thing was when I had my roof & gutters replaced recently, the gutter guy came by and dropped off some parts and gutter guards but didn't make the gutters. Next day he came back and made the gutters. Same truck - just didn't check his list the first time around. I didn't say anything because for all I knew the roofer was getting the actual gutters from somebody else. In any case, the seamless gutter making is pretty cool - and I see it all the time.

Comment: Most gutters _that you pay someone to install_ are made onsite, as you say. Most DIY gutters are not. I have some of each on my place--for some reason the PO didn't put gutters over the garage, so we had a skating rink out front every winter. Just rectified that situation this weekend. :)

Comment: @isherwood Good point. I never gave any serious thought to DIY roof or gutters - I like to keep my feet on the ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have fairly typical 5" aluminum or steel K-style gutters (virtually nothing is actually tin in the modern world). Almost any generic gutter guard should work.

I have oak trees and the simple perforated plastic panels work beautifully and they're super inexpensive. They slide under your shingles and slip onto the outer gutter edge, so size isn't critical. Unless you have conifer needles, that's what I'd suggest.

If you do have needles, look to the solid surface type.

Comment: Yup. Unless there's something specifically custom about the gutter (and there isn't anything custom about these), then any generic gutter guard will fit. Which ones will work is still up for debate (there are arguments for and against about every style out there).

Comment: Thanks @isherwood (+1) - are 5" aluminum gutters the **same** as _steel K-style gutters_, or are they different? If they are different, how can I tell which ones they are? Thanks again!

Comment: Yours look like aluminum to me due to the coloration on the inside. Use a magnet to test. It doesn't really matter, though. Aluminum and steel K gutter are virtually identical from a leaf guard fitment standpoint. 5" is a standard nominal size, but some variation is to be expected.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup when I was looking for gutter covers, almost everything was a universal fit. About the only unique thing I recall seeing was that the ones I purchased were designed specifically to work with the particular gutter hangers I purchased. I don't _think_ these covers would stay on well with a different hanger. However, most every other cover would have stayed on the gutter just fine, even with the hanger I picked.

Comment: *"virtually nothing is actually tin in the modern world"*  Well, [solder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin#Applications) is made of tin... arguably the thing that holds most of the *modern* world together, lol.  More to the point that most things we commonly call "tin" aren't actual tin at all. (ie: tin roof, tin pot, tin can, tin gutter guards, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to tell the make, but there's a way to tell the profile and the size of the gutter.

Basically, there are several different gutter manufacturers, and several companies that manufacture gutter machines. Those are all very similar if not exactly the same in a lot of cases.

1. By measuring the [gutter hanger](https://www.kmsheetmetal.com/shop/K-Style-Gutter-Hangers-c14737019) you have, you'll know if you have a 5" or 6" gutter, as those are standard gutter brackets (you have 5" because of your approximate dimension of 4.5" at the end cap).
2. That [end cap is an stamped product](https://www.kmsheetmetal.com/shop/K-Style-Gutter-End-Caps-c14737024), with a standard "R" (right side) marking, which leads me to believe its a standard seamless K-style gutter.

It's called seamless because its manufactured from a coil, so it can technically be made to infinite lengths.

Gutter installers typically have a machine and will cut to fit on site. Other companies will do cut and drop on site so you can install the gutter yourself which is pretty cost effective. However, if you can't find anything locally and need it shipped, you'll normally get them in 10' or 20' lengths, as those are standard skid sizes for freight companies to ship products on.

K-style gutters, like any other gutters can be custom manufactured with slight modifications, and by looking at a picture alone without the end cap would not be possible to say with 100% certainty what you have, however, what makes possible to tell yours is a **standard seamless 5" k-style gutter is the end cap and hanger size**.

Comment: I don't understand your final assertion. I see no reason to think that this is seamless gutter. In fact, the end cap style leads me to big-box brands which would come in fixed length. It's not relevant to the question, but how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: The fact that they come in fixed length just means they're cut to length, and that's  probably for shipping purposes or to make it easier to sell. It's still the same gutter, made from a coil that runs through a machine that can be made to any length. I don't know if the section in the image is seamless or not since the image is cutoff, if that's what you mean, but it is still the same gutter profile that was made with coil in a gutter machine.

Comment: Yep, but that's not what "seamless" means in the gutter industry. It means without butt joints, or seams between sections. Obviously any sheet metal form was made on a machine of some sort.

Comment: It is made from a seamless gutter machine, with roll formers which uses coil, is that better? Unless its a straight section with 2 end caps, no gutter is ever seamless if you want to get technical. The obvious distinction that I was making here is how it is made: as I mentioned vs. via sheet stock on a sheet metal brake (which it is not).